# C# DefaultValue reset itself after build

Tags: c#, textbox, components

I have a problem in a custom TextBox that i'm trying to make:

I'm trying to create a new property with a defaultValue of true to let the TextBox resize itself after textChanged but everytime i build the project even if i manually changed the value from the property window to false the value of the property reset itself to true.

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    new public bool AutoSize { get; set; } = true;  

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AutoSize == true)
        {
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font);
            Width = size.Width;
            Height = size.Height;
        }
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a backing field and use that:

```
    private bool _AutoSize = true;

    [Browsable(true)]
    new public bool AutoSize
    {
        get { return _AutoSize; }
        set
        {
            _AutoSize = value;
            UpdateStyles();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work, read here https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/311339/msdn-documentation-for-the-defaultvalueattribute-class-may-be-confusing

Comment: your methos works adding UpdateStyles(); at the end of the set (inside it, after this.autosize = value;). 
Modify it so i can set the answer to resolved for other people

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SampleEx : TextBox
    {
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(typeof(bool), "true")]
        new public bool AutoSize { get; set; }

        public SampleEx()
            : base()
        {
            this.AutoSize = true;            
        }
    }
```

In [DefaultValue(typeof(bool), "true")] and constructor you have to set true.
It will work for you.